# if HTML table contain images inside its rows, then how i can minimize the white space between the images

Tags: html, css, asp.net, sharepoint

I know there is a forum specifically for sharepoint, but my problem is more related to general CSS & HTML rather than sharepoint.
now i created an aspx page inside a sharepoint site, and i want to show a number of images underneath each other, and i chose to show the images inside a table to guarantee that i will always get 3 images per line, regardless of the end user screen size.

But the problem is that the images will have extra spaces between them as follow:-

[image]

although i defined the images width x height to be (60px X 59px) + the table width to be 17%, which is the minimum table width i can get. as if i decrement the width to be less than 17% nothing will be minimized. here are the settings for the images and the table:-

[image]
[image]

here is the markup for my table which contain images:-

```
<table class="ms-rteTable-0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 17%; height: 364px;">    
<tbody>
          <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-0">
             <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 30px; height: 81px;">​<a title="X" href="***" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/Resources/***.png" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px;"/></a></td>
             <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0" style="width: 30px; height: 81px;">​<a title="" href="*****" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/Resources/****.png" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px;"/></a></td>
             <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 30px; height: 81px;">​<a name="******" title="" href="***"><img alt="" src="/Resources/Smart%20Support%20Logo.png" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px;"/></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-0">
             <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 30px;">​<a title="t" href="*****" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/Resources/****.png" _moz_resizing="true" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px;"/></a></td>
             <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0" style="width: 30px;">​<a title="" href="h*****" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/Resources/***.png" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px;"/></a></td>
             <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 30px;">​<a title="" href="****" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/Resources/***.png" style="margin: 0px; width: 60px;"/></a></td>
          </tr>
```

so can anyone advice how i can minimize the space between the images? as seems inside the available UI options this is not possible.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use CSS ?

Comment: @TakitIsy yes i can define my own css..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add `cellpadding=0` and/or `cellspacing=0` on your `table` in the mark-up:

```html
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-0">
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-0">
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Or, using CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-0">
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-0">
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0">
        <a><img alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/60/60" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. sorry but i should have mentioned this before,, that my table already have `cellspacing="0"` defined..i updated my question with the compete markup.. now adding `cellpadding=0` did not do any difference.

Comment: yes i added the custom css ,, but unfortunately still the spaces are the same

Comment: @johnG Did you remove your inline styles when you tried with the CSS ? The inline  styles overrides the CSS.

Comment: i did not remove anything.. so which inline style you are referring to?

Comment: @johnG I'm referring to the `style` property in your HTML, i.e. `style="width: ..."`

Comment: thanks for the hint, now i remove all the inline styles, and i added the custom css, and the white spaces between the images got cleared out.. i had to re-size the images.. but on IE11 i still get the same white spaces,, while on chrome and Firefox the white spaces between images got removed correctly... so not sure why this is not working on IE11 !!